# Shopify speed tests for development theme (preview mode)

Tags: shopify, pagespeed

I'm new with shopify developemnt flow, maybe anyone can help me with my speed-related problem? I have a live theme and another one, development theme, so it there any way to check NOT live theme with Google speed tools? I don't want to go live with staging theme for it...

Answer (score 1):

Install the new theme in a [development store](https://help.shopify.com/en/partners/dashboard/development-stores). Then look for general speed issues of the theme. Of course the overall absolute performance of the development store is not the same as that of your production store.

Answer (score 1):

Testing on a dev store is a good option if you can install the same apps on your dev store (most of the time, paid app cannot be installed on a dev store).

- you could try the [shopify chrome theme inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopify-theme-inspector-f/fndnankcflemoafdeboboehphmiijkgp) to test
- you could use the [site audit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse#devtools) in chrome instead of google pagespeed

Answer (score 0):

just copy a link of preview mode and past it to Google Page Insight